Finding the Pythagorean triples for a given small side
I wish to find all Pythagorean triples containing a given number as one of it's small sides.
Take a right angled triangle $a,b,c$ small side $a$ and hypotenuse $c$.
Let $N=c-b$
Substituting into Pythagoras and solving for $2b$
2b=$\frac aN$ a - N
N must be even if $a$ is even as $c^{2}-b^{2}$  must then be even, hence $b$ and $c$ must be both odd or both even. Likewise if $a$ is odd $N$ must be odd.
If $a$ is odd $\frac{a}{N}$ must be an integer for us to get an integer from $\frac{a}{N}$ and hence $2b$.
Statement 1: If the small side a of a Pythagorean triple is odd, then the difference between the the second small side and the hypotenuse N must be 1 or a factor of a.
If a is even, N must be even hence we can write
2b=$\frac{\frac a2}{\frac n2}$a - N
or
2b=$\frac{a}{\frac n2}.\frac a2$ - N
By the same argument as for Statement 1, $\frac{N}{2}$ now must be a factor of a in order that it will multiply by $\frac{a}{2}$ (which is an integer as a is even) and then subtract N to get integer b.
Statement 2: If the small side a of a Pythagorean triplet is even and the difference between the other two sides is N  then $\frac{N}{2}$ must be 1 or a factor of a (less than $\frac{a}{2}$).
Are statements 1 and 2 true ?.

Welcome to MSE. Please write your expressions with proper formatting. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this on the site. I've had a go at most of it, to give you an example, but have left the gray boxes for you.

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\implies a^2 = c^2-b^2 = (c+b)(c-b)$ and if $a,b,c$ must be integers....  $a^2$ can only have so many factors.

This is most easily done using the formulas, $a=2rsk$, $b=(r^2-s^2)k$, $c=(r^2+s^2)k$ imply $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

The "small sides" are called the legs of the right triangle.

It is difficult to evaluate your question without knowing what version of "Pythagorus" you are using.
Opinions differ about whether the even "leg" should be $\,a\,$ or $\,b\,$ but some calculations are easier if it is $\,b\,$ as generated by Euclid's formula
\begin{equation*}
F(m,k)=
\begin{cases}
A=m^2-k^2\\ 
B=2mk\\ 
C=m^2+k^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
or a variation where $\,n\,$ produces the same triples as
$\,F\bigg((2m-1+k),k\bigg)$
\begin{equation*}
F(n,k)=
\begin{cases}
A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\\ 
B =\phantom{(2n-1)^2+{}} 2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\ 
C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
For all primitive triples, $\,C-B\,$ is an odd square, i.e. $\,C-B=(2n-1)^2, n\in\mathbb{N}\,$ and only half of primitive triples have either $\,a\,$ or $\,b\,$ as the smallest side as seen in this sample generated by the latter formula.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 &k=3 & k=4 & k=5\\ \hline
Set_1&3,4,5 &5,12,13&7,24,25&9,40,41&11,60,61\\ \hline
Set_2&15,8,17&21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65&39,80,89\\ \hline
Set_3&35,12,37&45,28,53&55,48,73&65,72,97&75,100,125\\ \hline
Set_{4}&63,16,65&77,36,85&91,60,109&105,88,137&119,120,169\\ \hline
Set_{5}&99,20,101&117,44,125&135,72,153&153,104,185&171,140,221\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
If we let $\,N\,$ be an odd square we can see
$\,N\in\{1,9,25,49,\cdots\}\implies n\in\{1,2,3,4\cdots\}.\quad$ Every member of each infinite set has the same $\,C-B\,$ difference.
It is better to choose a value $\,A=2x+1,x\in\mathbb{N}\,$ or
$\,B=4x,x\in\mathbb{N}\,$ and then find the corresponding triples as follows. Solve the function of that "side" for $\,k\,$ and test a defined range of
$\,n$-values so see which ones yield integers for $\,k$.
$$ A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\implies k=\frac{A-(2n-1)^2}{2(2n-1)}\\\text{for}\quad 1\le n\le\biggl\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{A+1}}{2}\biggr\rfloor $$
For example
$$A=99\implies   1\le n\le \bigg\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{99+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=5 \\\land\quad  n \in \{1,2,5\} \implies   k\in\{49,15,1\}$$
$$F(1,49)=(99,4900,4901)\quad F(2,15)=(99,540,549)\quad  F(5,1)=(99,20,101)$$
Note: $\,(99,540,549)=9(11,60,61).\,$ The formula generates odd square multiples of primitives when $\,GCD(2n-1,k)>1.$
$$B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\implies k=\frac{\sqrt{2B+(2n-1)^2)}-(2n-1)}{2}\\\text{for}\quad1\le n \le\frac{B}{4}$$
$$B=20 \implies  1\le n\le\frac{20}{4} =5\quad\land\quad n\in \{2,5\} \implies  k\in \{2,1\}$$
$$F(2,2)=(21,20,29\quad F(5,1)=(99,20,101)$$

Many thanks. My do-it-in-your-head method of getting a triple for any number is if odd then square it, take 1 and halve it, you then have the first of two consecutive.  if even then halve first then square it and you have the middle of two odd or even numbers. I presume my two statements are true that the factors determine how many others. I've got Pythagorean triples in the form of rectangles all over a load of masonic monuments. In particular they have specific sides of 17 and 40 and I wondered how hard it was to find these. It's trivial for any number to find at least one.

Using the methods I described,
$$A=17\implies   1\le n\le \bigg\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{17+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=2 \quad\land\quad  n \in {1} \implies   k\in{8}$$
$$F(1,8)=(17,144,145)$$
$$B=40 \implies  1\le n\le\frac{40}{4} =10\quad\land\quad n\in {1,10} \implies  k\in {4,1}$$
$$,F(1,4)=(9,40,41)\space GCD(1)\qquad F(10,1)= (399,40,401)$$

@Mark Lester Has my answer or my comment been useful to you? It is customary to upvote or downvote answers depending on whether or not they helped.

Since $c = b + N$ and $N$ is an integer the only thing you need is $b$ is also an integer, which means $\dfrac{a^2-N^2}{2N}$ is an integer. The consequences are:

$a^2 \equiv N^2 \mod{2}$
If $a$ is odd, $N$ is odd and $\dfrac{N(N-1)}{2N}$ is an integer. By substraction we have $\dfrac{a^2-N}{2N}$ being an integer, which means $a^2 = (2k+1)N$ or in other words, $N \mid a^2$
If $a$ is even, then let $N'=N/2$ and $a'=a/2$, then $b = \dfrac{(a')^2-(N')^2}{N'}$, therefore $N' \mid (a')^2$

Thus the neccessary conditions for $b$ to be an integer is $a^2\equiv N^2 \mod 2$ and $N'\mid (a')^2$ if $a$ is even and $N\mid a^2$ if $a$ is odd. It's also simple to show that these are sufficient.

I think N for odd and $\frac N2$ for even just needs to be a factor of a, not $a^2$

@MarkLester no it's not. There are cases where $N \mid a^2$ but $N \nmid a$. For example, if $a = 15$ then $N = 9$ is admissible. The corresponding triple is $(15,8,17)$. Another example is $(39,80,89)$

Oh thanks a lot. This was really what I was asking.  Now this one will come from 8 though, so if we only want the ones with a given small side then we just need <$\frac a2$
